# Looping through table and clicking spefic button on rows that match a certain criteria

Tags: python, html, selenium, pytest

I'm have a little struggle and ur help will be well appreciated.

I'm trying to navigate the script to go over this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRfF1.png) and if it sees "active" on a row, to perform delete for the row. The script should check all rows.

Currently the code have I have is :

```
class Test_Table_Test(BaseTest):
def test_table(self):
    self.driver.get('file:///loc/location')
    main_table = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body")
    main_table2 = main_table.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ftco-section")
    main_table3 = main_table2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".container")
    main_table4 = main_table3.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.row:nth-child(2)")
    body = main_table4.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")
    rows = body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
    cells = body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    #print(len(rows))

    for i in range(len(rows)):
        columns = rows[i].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
        for j in range(len(columns)):
            if columns[j].text == "Active":
                columns[4].click()
```

This is the html:
[the button is underlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZt6I.png)

Current result =  The test is passing, but it is not doing the job.

Comment: for this type of issue, you'd either have to share the entire table HTML in text format here or link to the page if it's a public URL. Also, we are not familiar with the web application that you are working therefore we would need to understand how to perform delete for the row.

Comment: It's resolved. Basically there was problem with the bootstrap. The code by itself was OK. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the bootstrap. The code it's ok. Closing the issue.